# Sending a variable from one page to another

Tags: php

I have two pages, one is for checking up on part information and the other is to order parts.

They both work independently but on the part information page it gets the information via AJAX when the user inputs a code. If the stock is below the minimum it says order x amount.

Now I would like to send the article code that the user has filled in to the order page so when he/she clicks on 'order' the user can immediately place the order on the other page.

I've seen a couple solutions like using a $_GET variable but this only works when the variable is predefined.

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: $_SESSION is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct your question, one solution is to use php session.

When you want to set something you use like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['something'] = "what you want";
```

And to read from session you will use:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['something'];
```

Comment: How can I put the user input into the session variable? Or would I need a form for that

Comment: You can use from form. Or via ajax when you make a call to PHP set a session with what you send via ajax.

Comment: I've tried it but can't get it to work, I use session_start than set the variable to the form variable and submit and go to the other page but the value is not showing. Only when I predefine the value, so how can I submit the form value?

Comment: How it's your code looking? do you save in session all the fields you want that are submitted?